# What does Costello's drawing symbolize?

Tags: analysis, the-departed

In *The Departed* there is a scene where Jack Nicholson's character makes a drawing. The drawing is of rats and the Massachusetts State House. He sets the drawing afire.

What is the symbolism of this scene?

Answer (score 4):

Since he knew there was a government agent in his team posing to be one of them, he was not certain if he was cop or FBI or CIA or the DEA as he was into all sorts of wild things. He feels the entire bureaucracy are filled with rats and needs to be burnt.

Answer (score 0):

It's also the very last shot of the movie after Matt Damon's Character is killed. Pans up to his balcony.
It's almost a premonition of the deaths of all of characters